# Having a number in

Tags: mysql, having

Can someone give me a query that will return as a result rows ID 1 & 3?

```
ID Name Hidden 
1 Mika 1,4,2 
2 Loca 0 
3 Nosta 4 
4 Like 2
```

Something like this 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Hidden HAVING(4)

Comment: BTW, `HAVING` means something totally different from this use case http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('4',Hidden);
```

docs for [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: just a note: single quotes are optional if you're looking for a number.

Comment: ya, i'm only looking for numbers , thanks again i really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(',',Hidden,',') LIKE '%,4,%'`

or you can avoid using LIKE like this

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE INSTR(CONCAT(',',Hidden,','), ',4,') > 0`

this will not get things like 40, 14, etc, but you need to make sure there are no spaces in the Hidden field (eg, `1, 4, 5` or update the concat and LIKE function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Hidden LIKE '%4%'
```

the % are wildcards.

Comment: That will also match '13,14,15'.

Comment: This would match any value containing 4, eg: 34, 44, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, i'm sorry because i  didn't referred to it before, but i  can't use  LIKE due to some performance functionality, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) might be a reasonable solution for this as long as you use the correct word breaks.

Comment: there isn't any way to do this without having to deal with fulltext search & LIKE ?

Comment: @Wiika:  There are probably quite a few ways.  One thing with full text search is that it can be extremely high performance.  So if you are dealing with large data sets, it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Either go with Full Text Search, as suggested, or

Spin the Hidden values off into a separate table, with the ID of current row.

Eg, Mika would have three entries in this table

ID = 1, Hidden =1

ID = 1, Hidden =4

ID = 1, Hidden =2

Then you could return results against this spin off table.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider normalizing the table and storing these "hidden" values in a separate table with an index on the apropriate column. Depending on the number of rows you have that would be much faster:

```
ID Hidden
1  1
1  4
1  2 
3  4 
4  2
```

and:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table.* FROM table, hidden_table WHERE table.ID = hidden_table.ID AND hidden_table.hidden = 4
```